# Handling PHP URL and GET requests

Tags: php, url, httprequest

I am currently parsing any given url, for example `example.com/page/1` or `example.com/api/info/1`, by exploding the URL:

```
$REQ = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
array_shift($REQ);
$REQ = array_filter($REQ, function($value) { return $value !== ''; });]
```

and then accessing its elements in the array like so:

```
if (count($REQ) > 1 && $REQ[0] == 'page' && $REQ[1] == '1'){
    \\ show page 1
}
```

But how could I handle (and access via array in the same way) a url that also includes GET elements, such as `example.com/page?id=1` or `example.com/api/info?=hello` ?

I am using nginx and trying files like below:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Comment: via [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), if its not working make sure you have QSA flag in your htaccess / rewrite rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse URL by `parse_url` function also for query params you can use `parse_str` function and extract all query parameters.

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api/info?param1=hello&param2=wrold';

$url_parts = parse_url($url);
var_dump($url_parts);
parse_str($url_parts['query'], $query_params);
var_dump($query_params);
```

Output:

```php
array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(5) "https"
  ["host"]=>
  string(11) "example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(9) "/api/info"
  ["query"]=>
  string(25) "param1=hello&param2=wrold"
}
array(2) {
  ["param1"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  ["param2"]=>
  string(5) "wrold"
}
```